# How I can solve $s(n)=n+s(n-1)$ by iteration method?

Tags: fixed-point-theorems

$$
s(n)=
\begin{cases}
0, \text{if $n=0$}\\
n+s(n-1), \text{if $n>0$}\\
\end{cases}
$$

Using the relation
\begin{align}
s(n) &= n+s(n-1) \\
&= n+n-1+s(n-2) \\
&= n+n-1+n-2+s(n-3) \\
&= \dots \\
&= n+n-1+n-2+\dots+1 \\
&= \dfrac{n^2+n}2 \\
&= \theta(n^2)
\end{align}

Is it right?

Comment: from what I can tell, that is correct.

Comment: When you do it just using ... instead of a summation it is easy to have one term too few or one term too many.  You have it right here.

Answer (score 1):

$s(n)=n+s(n-1)$

$s(n-1)=n-1 + s(n-2)$

$s(n-2)=n-2 + s(n-3)$

$s(n-3)=n-3 + s(n-4)$

.

.

.

$s[n-(n-1)]=n-(n-1) + s(0)$

⇒ $s(n)=n\times n -\frac{(n-1)(n-1+1)}{2}=n^2-\frac{(n)(n-1)}{2}=\frac{n^2+n}{2}$

Comment: @RossMillikan, you are right , I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I like to turn
recurrences to
telescoping sums
whenever possible.

From
$s(n) = n+s(n-1)
$
I get
$s(n)-s(n-1) = n$.

Summing both sides from $1$ to $m$,
$\sum_{n=1}^m s(n)-s(n-1) = \sum_{n=1}^m n $.

The left side telescopes into
$s(m)-s(0)$
and the right side is just
$\dfrac{m(m+1)}{2}
$.

Note that if
the first value is $s(1)$,
just make the sum from $2$
instead of $1$.